# RTP Fragmented Unit Header

Tags: c#, rtp

I'm working on RTP to send RTP packet with H264 data within his payload. At the moement i will try to use fragmented unit b over UDP. So i found that the payload of a fragmented unit b is composed of the Fragmented Unit Indicator, Fragmented Unit Header and finally the Fragmented Unit Payload.

[image: Fragmented Unit Header]

My question is about the Fragmented Unit Header. I saw that if it's the first fragment of the nal unit, the start bit must be set to one, if it's the last fragment the end bit must be set to one, the reserved bit must always be equals to 0.

The last 5 bits are reserved for the "nal unit payload type as defined in Table 7-1 of ITU-T Recommendation H.264.". The problem is that i didn't find the value these five last bits must have for H264, can someone help me ?

Thanks for your time !

Comment: https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi7hoa-3e7RAhWDyRQKHT0MAKYQFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.itu.int%2Frec%2Fdologin_pub.asp%3Flang%3De%26id%3DT-REC-H.264-200305-S!!PDF-E%26type%3Ditems&usg=AFQjCNGcityOpu3ZSLwMSE_cHDvdhhk0xQ&sig2=2tVyuzkva1CoVoK6lqGjmQ Page 48 Found by googling "Table 7-1 of ITU-T Recommendation H.264" :D

Comment: Tag "C#" does not apply if we are strict. That info is independent of the language you implement it in.

Comment: Ok Fildor. I will know it for my future questions, thx for your answers !

Comment: You're welcome. I hope you can use it. Would be nice if you could answer your own question if you manage to figure it out with the info from that documentation.

Comment: Yep, i finally found what i was looking for, in fact i was looking at section 7.1 instead of table 7.1 ^^